# I don't understand the solution to this java problem

Tags: java

Please help understanding the solution to this question.

Given 2 positive int values, return the larger value that is in the range 10..20 inclusive, or return 0 if neither is in that range.

max1020(11, 19) → 19
max1020(19, 11) → 19
max1020(11, 9) → 11

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
  if (b > a) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  }
  // Knowing a is bigger, just check a first
  if (a >= 10 && a <= 20) return a;
  if (b >= 10 && b <= 20) return b;
  return 0;
}
```

I can't understand the first IF statement block. Please help understand this portion.

```
if (b > a) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: If `b` is bigger than `a`, the `a` and `b` values get swapped.

Comment: it just Change the value a and b if b is greater than a, in your first example a=11 and b = 19, so the values will be swaped and a becomes 19 and b =11

Answer (score 1):

This code swaps the two numbers if b is greater than a. This will make sure that after this code you know that a will be bigger than b. Since you need to return the larger value that is between 10-20, you need to check the bigger number first if it satisfies the condition. The code below ensures that you will check the bigger number first.

```
if (b > a) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  }
// Knowing a is bigger, just check a first
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (b > a) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  }
```

If b is bigger than a. This part of code exchange values  for example:

if a = 8 and b = 10 after that you will have a = 10 and b = 8.

temp just help to exchange.

I hope it helps you!